# Relativity paradox with extreme speed

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

Consider:

The supermassive black hole in a galactic core.  A neutron star of nearly maximum mass does a **very** close flyby (remember, galactic black holes don't have the incredibly vicious tides of an ordinary one--it can get awfully close without crossing the Roche limit.)

Now, a neutron star can easily have an escape velocity of half of lightspeed.  What happens when it flies past at 86% of c (Lorentz factor = 2).  An observer sees it with half the radius in the line of motion and twice the mass--it's escape velocity is above lightspeed.  Thus the observer sees the object as a black hole.

It completes it's flyby and slows back down--the observer sees it go from being a black hole to being a neutron star--but that can't be.

Comment: You're correct: that scenario cannot occur. FWIW, modern treatments of relativity avoid the concept of relativistic mass, because it can be misleading like that. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/123208

Comment: Loren, I've downvoted your question for the "does not show any research effort" reason. Your question is an example of a frequently asked question here (which is why it was closed as a duplicate so quickly). The community does expect that users [thoroughly search for an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) here and elsewhere before posting.

Comment: @Alfred Please note that Loren cast the final duplicate vote. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/334566

Comment: @PM2Ring, thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Note that I envisioned a quite different scenario than the question it was a dupe of even though the fundamental issue is the same.